# Column it's not supposed to look at is 'out of domain'

Tags: ampl, glpk, mathprog

I get the following out-of-domain error, see below. The thing is, in the referred line, q comes out of the Qualities set, which does not even contain the LAT value. How can I prevent this from happening, and keep all my data in one table? I've been trying to work around it using the separate `latdata` table, but this looks ugly and redundant to me.

```
$ glpsol -m ron.mod
GLPSOL: GLPK LP/MIP Solver, v4.60
Parameter(s) specified in the command line:
 -m ron.mod
Reading model section from ron.mod...
Reading data section from ron.mod...
86 lines were read
Generating req...
ron.mod:20: cannot convert LAT to floating-point number
MathProg model processing error
MacBook-Air-van-Ron:examples raarts$ glpsol -m ron.mod
GLPSOL: GLPK LP/MIP Solver, v4.60
Parameter(s) specified in the command line:
 -m ron.mod
Reading model section from ron.mod...
Reading data section from ron.mod...
86 lines were read
Generating req...
ron.mod:20: data[DO_MINI,LAT] out of domain
MathProg model processing error
```

the source for ron.mod is below:

```
set AllProducts;
/* all products */

set Qualities;
/* minrequired */

param data{prod in AllProducts, {"price"} union Qualities};

param latdata{prod in AllProducts, "LAT"};
param maxallowed{"LAT"};

set Product := setof{ prod in AllProducts: latdata[prod, "LAT"] <= maxallowed["LAT"]} prod;

param minrequired{q in Qualities};

var x{p in Product}, integer, >= 0;

subject to req{q in Qualities}: sum{p in Product} data[p,q] * x[p] >= minrequired[q];

minimize cost: sum{p in Product} x[p] * data[p, "price"];

solve;

printf "aantal product         CPU   RAM    DISK  PR/STUK   TOTAAL\n";
printf{p in Product: x[p] != 0} "%6d %-12s %6d %6d %6d %8.2f %8.2f\n", x[p], p, data[p,"CPU"] * x[p], data[p,"RAM"] * x[p], data[p,"DISK"] * x[p],data[p,"price"], data[p,"price"] * x[p];
printf                    "%6s %-12s %6d %6d %6d %8.2s %8.2f\n", "", "", sum{p in Product} data[p,"CPU"] * x[p], sum{p in Product} data[p,"RAM"] * x[p], sum{p in Product} data[p,"DISK"] * x[p], "", sum{p in Product} data[p,"price"] * x[p];

data;

param data :    price  CPU     RAM     DISK    LAT :=
DO_MINI        5.00    1      512      20       2 
DO_SMALL      10.00    2     1024      30       2
DO_MEDIUM     15.00    2     2048      40       2
DO_LARGE      25.00    3     4096      75       2
SW_MINI        5.00    1     1024      10       3 
SW_SMALL      10.00    2     1024      15       3
SW_MEDIUM     15.00    2     2048      25       3
SW_LARGE      25.00    3     4096      50       3
BP_LARGE       5.00    3     4096      50       20
;

param latdata : LAT :=
DO_MINI         2  
DO_SMALL        2
DO_MEDIUM       2
DO_LARGE        2
SW_MINI         3  
SW_SMALL        3
SW_MEDIUM       3
SW_LARGE        3
BP_LARGE        20 
;

set AllProducts :=
DO_MINI   
DO_SMALL  
DO_MEDIUM 
DO_LARGE  
SW_MINI   
SW_SMALL  
SW_MEDIUM 
SW_LARGE  
BP_LARGE  
;

param minrequired :=
CPU                15
RAM             64000
DISK             1250
;

param maxallowed :=
LAT                 5
;

set Qualities :=
CPU
RAM
DISK
;

end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep all the data in one table by allowing `"LAT"` in the `data` parameter:

```
param data{prod in AllProducts, {"price", "LAT"} union Qualities};
```

Then `latdata` can simply copy the `LAT` data from it:

```
param latdata{prod in AllProducts} = data[prod, "LAT"];
```

This will solve the out of domain error because `('DO_MINI', 'LAT')` will be in the indexing set of `data` making this data statement valid:

```
param data :    price  CPU     RAM     DISK    LAT :=
DO_MINI        5.00    1      512      20       2  # <- data[DO_MINI, LAT]
...
```